# JavaFX set listview to be editable

Tags: java, javafx

I am kinda new to JavaFX, so maybe this is very easy to do. I have a `ListView<String>`, and what I want is that I can have a button which when pressed,  basically turns the selected String into a sort of text field in which you can edit the name of that specific item. I hope it is clear what I want. I already tried `list.setEditable(true)`, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to making the `ListView` editable you also need to make sure to use a `cellFactory` providing editable cells:

```
list.setEditable(true);
list.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
```

This way you can start a edit on a double click of a cell.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add an event to when the listitem is edited, with the old value and the new one?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#onEditCommitProperty , but make sure to update the `items` in the event handler, since `ListView` doesn't do the updates automatically, if you use a handler.

Comment: ok so one last question, I now have a `public void handle(EditEvent<String> event)` method in a `new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<String>>()` which is being called with `list.setOnEditCommit`. Is there a way I can get the old value?

Comment: Should be available via `event.getSource().getItems().get(event.getIndex());`.

Answer (score -1):

First, I'd use in this case a VBox filled with the TextFields. Those TextFields should have the editable property set to false. When you click on the button, you can call:

```
    ((TextField)vbox.getChildren().get(numberofTextFieldInList)).setEditable(true);
```

and now it should be editable. If you want the TextFields to look like Strings when not being editable, I would modify the aesthetic properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but first of all, I think a VBox filled with textfields does not look that good, and second of all, I want the items to also be selectable like items in a listview.